# Span jumping down when I have an img tag before

Tags: html, css, image

I am making a template for a site that im working on for myself... I have added a comment icon and a span to declare how much comments it is on the post. It is just a template of how I want it to be and it is not really working.

The thing is that the icon and the span (with the comment) jumps down a row and displace itself the post has an image:
[image: screenshot]

This is the post class I have every block in;

Without picture:

```
<a href="posts/post1.php" class="postlink">
  <div class="post">
    <img src="img\userprofile.png" alt="img\userprofile.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <p class="context">Random Text</p>
    <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><span class="comment">  300</span>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="posts/post2.php" class="postlink">
  <div class="post">
    <img src="img\userprofile.png" alt="img\userprofile.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <img src="img/baugette.jpg" width="220" height="150" class="postimg">
    <p class="context">Random Text</p>
    <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><span class="comment">  500</span><br>
  </div>
```

With picture:

```
<a href="posts/post1.php" class="postlink">
  <div class="post">
    <img src="img\userprofile.png" alt="img\userprofile.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <p class="context">Random Text</p>
    <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><span class="comment">  300</span>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="posts/post2.php" class="postlink">
  <div class="post">
    <img src="img\userprofile.png" alt="img\userprofile.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    <img src="img/baugette.jpg" width="220" height="150" class="postimg">
    <p class="context">Random Text</p>
    <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><span class="comment">  500</span><br>
  </div>
```

And this is the ONLY CSS code for that image:

```
img.postimg {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Comment: don't you mean that your element (the "random text") is being moved to the right when an image is used? That is a logical behavior because an image needs space. That space is then taken. Fortunately there are ways to solve it. But I am not sure if that is your problem.

Comment: Both the "random text" and the comment icon + span is moving. And it is the comment thingy that i am disturbed on

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your image and text in separate divs like below

```
<a href="posts/post1.php" class="postlink">
  <div class="post">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img\userprofile.png" alt="img\userprofile.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p class="context">Random Text</p>
        <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><span class="comment">  300</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

and then specify width in css for these elements.

```
.image{
    width:50%;
}
.text{
    width:50%;
}
```

try changing `width values` and try adding `float:left` or `float:right`